# what is the proof for matrix multiplication being commutative

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, math-software, matrix-calculus

I understand that if we have matrix $A$ and $B$
then $A \cdot B \neq B \cdot A$ 
as when you multiply the matrices in a different order, then their cells will shift in another form, thus making their multiplication equate differently in their product matrix.

but what is valid proof i can give to illustrate this

All help is much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean the proof for matrix multiplication being **non**-commutative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counter-example would suffice here. Take for example the following:
$$\begin{align*}
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} & = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}\\
& \qquad\not\parallel\\
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} & = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Does anyone know how to a) remove the manual spacing hack of the $\ne$ and b) rotate said symbol by $90^\circ$?

Comment: for the spacing you might be able to do something with the `align` environment.  Don't know about rotating the symbol though.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's already aligned. array will do this, but not quite worth it if rotatebox doesn't work :(

Comment: \nparallel kinda looks like \ne rotated ...

Comment: Testing... $\nparallel$ The slash is the wrong way but thanks :)

Comment: @AlexR: Modulo a reflection :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `graphicx` isn't among the supported packages. That would have made it so easy: `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\ne}`...

Comment: The very clumsy `\diagdown\hspace{-7.7 pt}||` works OK.

Comment: @String Thanks, I tweaked it to `\small\diagdown\hspace{-6pt}||`: $\small\diagdown\hspace{-6pt}||$ cf. $\displaystyle\ne$

Comment: @AlexR: That actually looks quite nice. But to have `graphicx` among supported packages would be even nicer, though!

Comment: @String I second that. Or something as powerful as `tikz`, but that's wishful thinking I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The only proof you need here is an example that shows you that, sometimes, $AB \neq BA$.  For example, try
$$
A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$
We find
$$
AB = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad BA = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$